# evitar comportamiento de etiqueta de anclaje

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola tengo un sistema que al presionar un enlace, verifica si el usuario está logueado y dependiendo de esto el enlace cambia; me funciona bien pero si el usuario no está logueado aun entra en la sección y luego rápidamente se redirecciona a la página que quiero, la idea es que no entre en la sección sino que redireccione de una vez a la página que quiero.

```html
<div id="r">
 <?php
  foreach ($mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM r') as $fila) {
   echo "<div class='card-action'>
          <a href='"; echo isset($_SESSION['id']) ? "#" : "./gin.php"; echo "' class='rr'>reservar</a>
          <input type='text' value='".$fila['id']."'>
         </div>";
      }
    ?>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#r").on('click','a.rr',function(){
        var id = $(this).siblings('input').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "vation.php",
          data: { id:id },
          success: function(data) {
            $('#r').html(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Un ejemplo de lo mas cercano que necesito sería como reservar algo; si el usuario se encuentra registrado continúa normalmente de lo contrario debería llevarlo a registrarse y no permitir el flujo normal.

Comment: Hay que revisar cómo gestionas las cosas en `vation.php`, ahí está el *quid*  de la cuestión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hace falta que ejecutas un ajax para comprobar si el usuario está registrado, ya que vas a redireccionar en cualquier caso, puedes hacer la comprobación en la pagina destino y dependiendo del estado del usuario mostrar una coso u otra.

En tu caso:

```
<div id="r">
    <?php
    foreach ($mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM r') as $fila) {
        echo "<div class='card-action'>
                <a href='reservar.php?material=".$fila['id'] . "' class='rr'>reservar</a>
             </div>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

y en **reserva.php** :

```
<?php
 if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
   include('login.php');
  } else {
   include('reserva_material.php');
 }

?>
```

Es solo una aproximación muy básica, pero haría lo que pides. 
Tienes que prever también como quieres que se comporte después de loguearse, seguramente te interese que continúe con la reserva.

> Fíjate que modifiqué el ancla que comentas en la pregunta, un `<a>`y
>   un  `<input>` no funcionan en conjunto como tu has puesto.  O usas un
>   `<form>` con `<input>`  o usas un `<a>` con parámetros en la url